# Is there a way to set preferences defaultValue per themes?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I have several themes in my application for different customers and would like to set a different `android:defaultValue` for each Themes. In my case this is in order to set a diferent default host.

I tried to set it using attibutes and Themes but I couldn't achieve it.

Define attribute in attrs.xml:

```
  <attr name="settings_host" format="reference" />
```

Definition of the different default values in a settings.xml file in res/values:

```
  <string name="settings_host_1">my.host1.net</string>
  <string name="settings_host_2">my.host2.net</string>
```

Chose the default value in themes.xml:

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/ApplicationTheme">
    <item name="settings_host">@string/settings_host_1</item>
```

Seth defaultValue in preferences:

```
  <EditTextPreference
      android:name="Host"
      android:defaultValue="@attr/settings_host"
      android:key="@string/settings_tag_mw_host"
      android:summary="@string/act_settings_host_summary"
      android:title="@string/act_settings_host" />
```

I tried also:

```
      android:defaultValue="?settings_host"
```

Unfortunately this is not working, my default value is always empty. Did I do something wrong? Is there another way to achieve my goal?

The documentation says it is possible:
[Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3adefaultValue)

```
android:defaultValue
```

...

*May be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wrong, I had a second preference file in `xml-v14` that I forgot to edit with the new attribute. As my test device version is new enough to use this second preference, the default value stayed empty.

The solution described in the question works.